# Autoclose PysimpleGUI after 1 second

Tags: user-interface, pysimplegui

I want to auto close this PySimpleGUI after 1 second, however it seems not to work.

```
    font = ('Areal', 11)
    sg.theme('BrownBlue')

    data = Output

    headings = ['Column1','Column2','Column3']

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    headings = df.columns.tolist()
    data = df.values.tolist()

    layout = [[sg.Table(data, headings=headings, justification='left', key='-TABLE-')],
            [sg.Button('Run'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

    sg.Window("Overview", layout).read(close=True)
```

Any suggestion would we very welcome

Comment: Add one more option `timeout=1000`, like `sg.Window("Overview", layout).read(timeout=1000, close=True)`, it will generate an event `sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT` after 1000ms, then close the window.

Comment: @JasonYang Thanks a lot, works perfectly.

I was hoping that the whole script would update fast enough so the user would not see it. Could I use `update` or `refresh` instead? 

The purpose of closing it was to update, but the script is a bit to slow

Comment: Not sure what it is for your simple description.